# Silverlight. Cannot find VisualTreeHelper GetDescendantBounds

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Cannot find method in silverlight VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(item).
Do you know any analogs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no GetDescendantBounds in silverlight. 
But Charles Petzold posted analog here:

http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/11/250534.html